# infinite loop on printing 2D array

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>


void main()
{
    char plaintext[50];
    char key[20];
    int plain=0,max1=0,max2=0; // max2 amount of coloumn n max1 for row on chip
    char chip[30][30];
    int i,j,k=0,c=0;

    printf("Enter key :");
    scanf("%s",&key);

    for(i=0;key[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        max2++; 
    }

    printf("Enter plaintext :");
    scanf("%s",&plaintext);

    for( i = 0; plaintext[i] != '\0'; i++ ) 
    {
        plain++; 
    }
    if (plain%max2==0)
    max1=plain/max2;
    else
    max1=plain/max2+1;
    while(plaintext[k]!='\0')
    {

        for (i=0;i<max1;i++)
        {
            for (j=0;j<max2;j++)
            {
            chip[i][j]=plaintext[k];
            k++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s",chip[0][0]);
}
```

1st im trying to move the string on plain (1D array) into chip(2d array) with dynamic array on the 2D but when im trying to run this code it show nothing than stopped working.. is there anything goes wrong with my 2D array?

Comment: `printf("%s", chip[0][0])` looks wrong.

Comment: I suggest using `strlen` for calculating `max2` and `plain`, but that has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: H2CO3 is entirely correct. That single line will fault your process (likely). And any decent compiler will tell you the format string specifier doesn't match the argument provided. (clang certainly does =P)

Comment: oh ok the stopped work thing done but nothin showed when i use print.. any other error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled it on Linux (after omitting the void because in Linux main has to return a value) and I got "Segmentation fault". I guess it is because of `printf("%s",chip[0][0]);`, it should be `printf("%s",chip[0]);`

I mean chip[0][0] returns a specific character in the chip[0] and you want to print the first string in chip array, right?

Comment: ah okkay but now let say printf("%c",chip[0][2]) but nothin show up there.. anything wrong with my code?

Comment: it depends on what the user has entered in `key`. that's why i suggest to initialize chip (using `memset()` probably) avoiding unexpected values. if you give me more details what are the values of `key` and `plaintext` and what you expect to get, i can give you more details. :)

Comment: its bout encrypting key gonna be number tht will encrypt the plain text.. n plain text gonna be message tht gonna be encrypt.. n bout memset() wht it is im new on programming hre :(